# Databinding to Property of class that in another class with property

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

What is the correct way to perform databinding if the property (the context in this case) that i bind to is a **class (LatestReading class)** with **its property (Unit)**.

The datacontext is set to the root of the class. Here's the hierarchy of my class. MonitoringPoint.LatestReading.Unit

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TrackBallInfoTemplate"
              DataType="{x:Type winGRAPH_Core:MonitoringNode}">
    <StackPanel Margin="3">
        <Grid Height="Auto">
            <StackPanel Height="Auto"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"                                       
                           Text="{Binding DataPoint.Value, FallbackValue=0.00}"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           FontSize="16" />
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Text="{Binding LatestReading.Unit, FallbackValue=°C}"
                           Margin="2,3,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="Auto">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Text="{Binding DataPoint.Category, FallbackValue=time}"
                       d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height"
                       FontStyle="Italic"
                       Margin="0,2,0,0" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Do you mean if the DataContext is set to an instance of a class (LatestReading in your case)?

Comment: DataContext is set to the root class in this case. There's the hierarchy. MonitoringPoint.LatestReading.Unit

Comment: So does the binding just not work as the syntax looks correct. Are there any binding errors in the Visual Studio Output window?

Comment: I'm getting the right data in the UI but not in the output window. The error in the output windows read as "System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'LatestReading' property not found on 'object' ''DataPointInfo' (HashCode=26599850)'. BindingExpression:Path=LatestReading.Unit; DataItem='DataPointInfo' (HashCode=26599850); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')"

Comment: Looks like it's trying to find a property called LatestReading on a class of type `DataPointInfo`, not a `MonitoringPoint` as you mentioned should be above it in the hierarchy. Where are you setting the DataContext and are you sure it's not being set in any child controls to something else?

Comment: DataPointInfo was the template i customize. http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radchartview-features-trackball.html I wanted to datatemplate to show the value of my class property.

Comment: I think you're going to have to show a lot more of the XAML, otherwise it's going to be pretty difficult to work out what is going on.

Comment: You could try `DataItem.DataPoint.LatestReading.Unit`.

Answer (score 0):

If the type that is assigned to your DataContext is a `LatestReading` then just use the property `Unit`. The DataContext already set at a higher level (**if** you've remembered to set it - it's a common mistake to forget) automatically cascades to the child controls.

Comment: My class hierarchy is MonitoringPoint.LatestReading.Unit.